# Detect credit card type American Express or American Express Corporate

Tags: javascript, credit-card

I've created a javascript to detect credit card type but there's one problem. I didn't find differences between American Express and American Express Corporate. Is there any differences or that's impossible to know when the user are using American Express Corporate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issuer Identification Number (IIN), as you may know, is contained within the first six digits of the card number. However, some card issuers such as American Express are so large they can be identified by less than six digits.

For the most part, American Express uses the last four digits of the IIN to represent the type of card as listed [here](http://www.stevemorse.org/ssn/List_of_Bank_Identification_Numbers.html#American_Express_.2837.2A.2A.2A.2A.29). I cannot confirm the validity of this source, but it appears to have been a past Wikipedia page. Use at your own risk. It is most definitely out of date.

The article states the following ranges denote a corporate card (differentiated by country):

- 374996 - FR
- 375790 - SE
- 3758**  - CH

This is just speculation, but I am guessing Wikipedia removed the article due to inaccuracy or the overhead of maintaining the list with new cards coming out every day. Unfortunately, this was the closest source I could find.

My suggestion would be to attempt to contact American Express directly as this might lead to a more satisfactory response.